# Failing to read data from an excel sheet with where clause in select statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel

I am trying to read data from an excel sheet but there is an exception saying that no value given for one or more required parameters which I don't understand. Here is my code upto where the error is pointing to:

```
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
    ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Staff Contracts.xlsx; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO""")
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
    ("select * from [Staff Contracts$A4:K14] where I=176", MyConnection)
MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
```

The exception points to that last line `MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)` which shows me that there is a problem with my select statement. Previously my code reads the data and displays it without the `where` clause in the select but when I added the `where` statement so that it can only read data from rows where the column `I` has a value equal to 176, it instead gives an exception that shows that some required parameter is missing a value

Comment: Can that be a reason for not working when I add the where statmt?

Comment: And you are sure the presence of "where I=176" is the only difference between it working and the error? What about the data type of the I column? Are you sure its not text, and the criteria should be "where I='176'"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of HDR = NO, I column will become F9 because oledb will name the column F1.. Fn for it's internal reference.

```
MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Staff Contracts$A4:K14] where F9=176", MyConnection);
```

In this case the OLEDB driver will create columnnames for each column in the selection (F1 to Fn). so if you change the range "A4:K14" to "B4:K14" then column F9 will be F8.

Comment: Thank you so much @Romil. Using F9 got it working. Do you mind telling me why `I` does not work and has to be replaced with F9. looks to me that F9 is just like a place holder the datagridview when there is no header. Is it?